# FileNotFoundException while running Spring and Ibatis based application on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

I am using Spring, ibatis for ORM. My `app-config.xml` look like

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.50/lmexdb_v1" />
    <property name="username" value="lmexdba" />
    <property name="password" value="lmexdba123#" />
</bean>

<bean id="sqlMapClient" class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation"
        value="classpath:com/platysgroup/lmex/server/mobile/dao/ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml" />
</bean>


<bean id="mobileController" class="com.platysgroup.lmex.server.controller.MobileController">
    <property name="announcementService" ref="announcementService"></property>
    <property name="courseService" ref="courseService"></property>
    <property name="userService" ref="userService"></property>
</bean>
```

and I have my `sqlmapconfig.xml` file in `src/webapp/spring.`

But when I run my application on tomcat it show me a exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/platysgroup/lmex/server/mobile/dao/ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: would you tried add a '/' in start? like that classpath:/com/platysgroup/lmex/server/mobile/dao/ibatis/SqlMapConfig.xml

Answer (score 1):

put it in `src` , and it will be available

if you are using maven project then add it to `resource`

Comment: i try this also but it's showing me a same exception. and i have other projects also in which i have used this type of config all other are working fine but i don't know what is issue in this project

Comment: in your web.xml there should be context-config-location tag something like that. where it points to ?

Comment: i don't have a context-config-location tag in my web.xml, but i have <context:component-scan> tag in my spring config.xml

Comment: i write my context-component-tag as below in my app-config.xml file   <context:component-scan base-package="com.platysgroup.lmex.controller"></context:component-scan>

Comment: I am asking about  `context-config-location `